# WebRTC Ice failed, signaling proces

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have some troubles with my WebRTC application. The app is simple, just a client and receiver. The client should sent their media, cam, audio or screen to the receiver. Then the receiver should show the incoming streaming.

The troubles start with the signaling process I guess. Just the console. It says:

```
ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details
```

For develop this app I followed the tutorial [Felix Hagspiel's Blog](http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/create-your-own-videochat-application-with-html-and-javascript) but I am unable to make it work in my system and share the media.

I did not define stun server because I'm on the same machine and the same network, so it do not need to do a Transversal NAT to know the IP of the peers. I just read this in a question here in Stackoverflow.

I do not want to somebody write my app, only I need to know where it could fail to try to resolve by myself. I just searching information about 4 days but nothing help me.

I am using Firefox 45.0.1 on Linux (Manjaro) with the client and the receiver. For the signaling server is a NodeJS app.

The code is in a pastebins:

- [Websocket Server](http://pastebin.com/tGFzz5Kf)
- [Receiver](http://pastebin.com/5ZFrVMuJ)
- [Client](http://pastebin.com/zLByPyMk)
- [webrtc.js](http://pastebin.com/Fybv9xuv)

For last the about:webrtc log. [Log](http://pastebin.com/aHCAzL8w). The file **Cliente_New.html** is the *Client* and the file **Pi_new.html** is the **Receiver**

Comment: There are so many problems with your code. I would suggest you to firstly apply the official samples from WebRTC team for the basic understanding of establishing a WebRTC connection. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/js/main.js

Comment: Way too much code. See https://jsfiddle.net/2v1Lnpmx/

Comment: @jib I never see Javascript like this but I could understand it a little bit and reduce to minimum the code and know is working by your example. Thank you

Comment: @Tresdin Thank you too. I just see that examples and helped me a little bit with the process of signaling. Thank you